# How to make vertical frame label read top down

Tags: plotting

In Mathematica, default frame label will put labels at the bottom and the left. The label on the left reads from the bottom to the top. I would like to also put label on the right of the frame, but this label also reads from bottom to top. How can I make the right label read from top down?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply `Rotate` the label by 180 degrees:

```
Plot[, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"foo", "bar", "baz", Rotate["qux", 180 Degree]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm looking for.